# Cannot implicitly convert type 'char[]' to 'string[]'

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, char

strArr is the complete string which I am splitting to get different titles n date  but i want them in a string array. the moment I apply .
`ToArray() {in string[] titl = item.Title.ToArray();}`

the error message

> {Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'string[]'} changes to
>   {Cannot implicitly convert type 'char[]' to 'string[]'}

. Everything in class Data is also of string type

```
public class Data
{

    public string Date
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Title
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

string xml1 = Search();
```

string[] strArr = xml1.Split('|');

```
    int i,j;
Data item = new Data();

 for (i = 0; i < strArr.Count(); i = i + 2)

        {
            if (strArr[i].ToString() != "")
            {
                item.Title = strArr[i];
                string[] titl = item.Title.ToArray();
            }
        }
        for (j = 1; j < strArr.Count(); j = j + 2)
        {
            item.Date = strArr[j];
            string[] Dat = item.Date.ToArray();

        }
```

Comment: You haven't shown us the declaration of `strArray`, which doesn't help. Is it a string, or is it an arrya of strings?

Comment: @JonSkeet OP said it was of type `string`.

Comment: If you're working with a `string`, why are you calling `ToArray` on it? Do you want to work with individual characters?

Comment: Why do you want it to be an array in the first place?

Comment: @Nancy Perhaps you want to show us what `strArr` contains.

Comment: At a wild guess, you're looking for the [`Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method (i.e. you have a *delimited* string that you want to break on the delimiters).

Comment: So *firstly* that's a confusing name. Next, how would you expect `strArray[i].ToString()` to be an empty string? What are you expecting `strArray[i]` to be?

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry for the confusion i have just updated my question

Comment: Right, so it's *not* a string - it's a string array. Aside from anything else, that means you don't need to call `ToString` on it... Why are you calling `ToArray()` at all?

Comment: @JonSkeet I guess she was trying to get Data[] as an array of Title+Date as in Shaharyar's answer

Comment: @Nancy You was always assigning title and date to the same instance of item. To get an array of item try Shaharyar's answer.

Comment: The big problem here is we don't really know what you're trying to achieve. It would really help if you'd provide a short but complete program with input and expected output...

Answer (score 1):

Calling `.ToArray()` on a string returns `char[]`, not `string[]`. There is not implicit conversion between those two types.

To make this work try this:

```
string[] titl =
        item.Title.ToCharArray().Select(c => c.ToString()).ToArray();
```

---

Per your comment below, try this:

```
var xml1 = "X|A|Y|B|Z|C|W|D";
var strArr = xml1.Split('|');

var items =
    strArr.Where((x, n) => n % 2 == 0)
        .Zip(
            strArr.Where((x, n) => n % 2 == 1),
            (t, d) => new Data()
            {
                Title = t,
                Date = d
            })
        .ToArray();
```

I get this result:

[image: result]

Comment: I don't think the OP actually wants each character as string.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov - I thought that's what he wanted. Or are you saying you think he just wants a single string array?

Comment: I think the OP actually has some sort of delimited string he needs to split.

Comment: @Nancy - It's not returning `char`. I've tested this code. It will do this: `"ABC"` => `{ "A", "B", "C" }` - not `{ 'A', 'B', 'C' }`.

Comment: @Enigmativity thanks i will try some other way out then :)

Comment: @Nancy - If this isn't working for you then you haven't described your problem correctly. What is it about this approach that doesn't work the way you want?

Comment: @Nancy - Your title is "Cannot implicitly convert type 'char[]' to 'string[]'" - I've answered against the title and the first few lines of the question. From the point when you define the class `Data` the question isn't very clear.

Comment: @Enigmativity yup but i want "ABC|DEF" => {"ABC","DEF"}

Comment: @Enigmativity I agree it is not very clear, but maybe you missed the last part of "I am splitting to get different titles n date **but i want them in a string array**"

Comment: @Nancy - I've appended my answer with something I think should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

`string.ToArray()` returns a `char` type array.

As you need all title and dates you should have an array of type `Data`:

```
string xml1 = Search();
string[] strArr = xml1.Split('|');

int totalitems = strArr.Length / 2; //get Titles count
Data[] items = new Data[totalitems];    //initialize array of data

for (int i = 0; i < strArr.Length; i = i + 2)
{
    //new instance of Data
    if(items[i/2] == null)
        items[i/2] = new Data();

    if (strArr[i].ToString() != "") //get title
    {
        items[i/2].Title = strArr[i];
    }
    if (strArr[i + 1].ToString() != "") //get date
    {
        items[i/2].Date = strArr[i + 1];
    }
}
```

You don't need 2 `for` loops anymore.

Comment: Data.length is not working. Data is a class with Title and date in it

Comment: Sorry, that was a typing mistake. It is `items.Length`

Comment: i need this titl variable later in my code and if i am doing like    var titl=items[i].Title so again it is giving the same error of char[] to string[] :(

Comment: @Shaharyar If you loop i checking against items.Length instead of strArr.Length you will read only the first half of items

Comment: @BlasSoriano No, I am accessing `strArr` in `for` loop body with `i` and `i + 1`. I'll traverse complete array

Comment: @Shaharyar No, you will traverse just the first half, and besides that you will get an exception trying to assign the date to items[i + 1] (you just initialized items[i])

Comment: @BlasSoriano Thats right. Thanks for pointing out the error :)

Answer (score 0):

The ToArray method on string gives you character array. You can select character as a string with linQ Select method.

```
string[] titl = item.Title.Select(c=>c.ToString()).ToArray();
```

You probably need to re-think that if you want the string array or character array as if you want the character array then you need to change the declaration of the title array from `string` to `char`.

```
 char[] titl = item.Title.ToArray();
```

Comment: this is not working i have already tried this

Comment: Could you explain what is not working, as I am getting char array with the second statement I have in my answer

Comment: string[] titl = item.Title.Select(c=>c.ToString()).ToArray(); is returning char array but i need string array

Comment: It is returning string array otherwise it wont be compiled you can check the type ot titl if it is string array or not by titl.GetType()